# run symfony2 app with docker [File not found.]

Tags: php, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run my symfony app with docker. I have downloaded this bundle [eko/docker-symfony](https://github.com/eko/docker-symfony)

I have copy my symfony project inside of my docker directory.

If I refresh with localhost, I have this error:  File not found.

If I put port 81 after localhost the page of Kibana will shop up.

When I run `docker ps`, I have noticed that the IP of all my containers is `0.0.0.0`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    db:
        image: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
            MYSQL_USER: symfony
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
    php:
        build: ./php-fpm
        expose:
            - "9000"
        volumes:
            - ./symfony:/var/www/symfony
            - ./logs/symfony:/var/www/symfony/app/logs
        links:
            - db
    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - php
        volumes_from:
            - php
        volumes:
            - ./logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
    elk:
        image: willdurand/elk
        ports:
            - "81:80"
        volumes:
            - ./elk/logstash:/etc/logstash
            - ./elk/logstash/patterns:/opt/logstash/patterns
        volumes_from:
            - php
            - nginx
```

**symfony.conf**

```
server {
    server_name symfony.dev;
    root /var/www/symfony/web;


    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony_access.log;
}
```

[image: picture]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is port 80. This probably looks on your host for a file.

You can either try to run nginx under a different port f.e. 8001

```
nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "8001:80"
```

and call

http://localhost:8001

or use a hosts name. To quote the readme of eko/docker-symfony

> ...and do not forget to add symfony.dev in your /etc/hosts file.

like

```
127.0.0.1 symfony.dev
```

Then you can call

http://symfony.dev

Comment: In my host file I have added this line `:# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
# 172.18.0.3      symfony.dev` If I run `docker ps`  I can see that the ip address is `0.0.0.0` for all my containers. When I refresh my page with `http://localhost:8001` or `http://symfony.dev` I have this error : the page can't be reach.

Comment: I'm using docker for windows 10  and the subnet address IP: `10.0.75.0`

Comment: that looks like the lines are commented by # and why is it `172.18.0.3 symfony.dev` ?

Comment: I have replaced this ip 172.18.0.3 by 127.0.0.1. I have remove the hash symbol next to the ip. now if i'm going to http://symfony.dev:81/ kibana show up , but the page with symfony.dev still doesn't work.

Comment: what error do you get? and is the port for nginx still 80:80 ?

Comment: no , now the port is 8001. symfony.dev:8001 - > `The symfony.dev page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: that looks like the routing is actually working but nginx has some error, can you check the errorlogs in logs/nginx and logs/symfony?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134102/discussion-between-sirius-and-ivoba).